# Github Pages: Page build failed

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm constantly getting the following error messages from github when I try to push my Jekyll site to their pages.

> The page build failed with the following error:
>
> Page build failed. For more information, see
>   https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-github-pages-build-failures.
>
> If you have any questions please contact us at
>   https://github.com/contact.

I ran `jekyll serve` to see if anything suspicious is going on, but the only thing it gives me is a warning: `Build Warning: Layout 'default' requested in app/index.html does not exist.`

Am I missing something? All my files are on Github: https://github.com/BobWassermann/confguide

Comment: It's probably a good idea to fix that warning, for starters.

Comment: @chris. Well, that's another issue. Default layout *does* exist.

Answer (score 1):

Github pages is looking for your files at the root of your repository, then as it doesn't find _layouts and so on, at the right place, the build fails.

To avoid this, in `config.yml` add `source: app`.

Note: As your repository will be served at `https://github.com/BobWassermann/confguide`, all links to your assets will fail.

To avoid this, in `config.yml` add `baseurl: /confguide`.

And in `default.html` call your assets with `{{site.baseurl}}` like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.baseurl}}css/syntax.css">
```

and same for other assets (css/js/img).

Answer (score 1):

Tried everything above, but nothing helped.
Went trough everything and found the bug. Github does not support a "_" folder in your images directory, even if it's in your copy task in Gruntfile.

Removing my "_posts" folder in the img folder solved this issue.